# hiding menu when scrolling Up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following script (in snippet) which hides my menu (nav) when user scrolls down and brings it back when they scroll up.

However it is not working and I am not sure where the issue lies

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }}    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
.nav-up { top: -100px; }

#s-nav { 
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%; height: 100px;
 padding-top: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="s-nav" class="nav-down">
  <p>navigation</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: better to setup snippet here

Comment: I remade the code into a snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because [id is more specify than class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

You can use debugger to find it out by yourself: 
[image: how to find it out]

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var didScroll;
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    didScroll = true;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
      hasScrolled();
      didScroll = false;
    }
  }, 250);

  function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
      // Scroll Down
      $('nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
      // Scroll Up
      if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
});
```

```css
#s-nav.nav-up {
  top: -100px;
}
#s-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}
.content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="s-nav" class="nav-down">
  ... nav content ...
</nav>
<div class='content'>
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! one quick addition, how can I add extra time/pixels to when it hides? It is set to do it at the nav's height, can I make it do it like 2x that heigh for example

Comment: remove `else`, intead add reverse condition, in first condition compare to `navbarHeight * 2`